# React Native Push Notification Linking to Specific Page

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am really new to react native (CRNA) and am currently trying out some push notifications with Expo.

Splash Screen: (I registered and listened for the push notification when the splash screen loads)

```
componentDidMount() { 
   var subscription = Notifications.addListener(this.handleNotification);
   registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
}

handleNotification(notification) { 

   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
   navigate('MainScreen', { data: notification })
}
```

I am receiving the push notifications, but can't forward it to the page I want. The screen is declared in the StackNavigation in App.js, however, this.props seems to be null when the function is called. I am not too sure why is it so and am trying to use deep linking instead.

Could someone share some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and moved the push notification handler to the navigation parent component. Add a reference to your navigation:

`<Nav ref={app => { this.app = app; }} />`

Then you can use

`this.app.navigate(...)`

in handleNotification